# Border disappears on zoom out

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a following html on my page:

```
<div style="height:70px;width:280px;margin:0px;padding:0px;border:1px solid #E2E2E2">
<div style="width:39px;height:70px;float:left;margin:0px;padding:0px">s</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" style="width:235px;float:left;height:70px;padding:0px;padding-left:5px;border-left:1px solid #E2E2E2;border-right-style:none;border-top-style:none;border- bottom-style:none;line-height:26px" runat="server" />
</div>
```

This works fine, howewer when you zoom out to say around 70%,60% and so on, the border disappears. I am facing the issue on my IE browser.

Any ideas where am i going wrong?

Comment: Try with border:5px; and check whether you do face same problem, again ?

Comment: You are going wrong by zooming out :) I have always coded to 100%, I don't think zooming caused issues are real issues :p

Comment: If i add a border:5px, it works fine until you zoom out to around 15%. But i cannot have such a thick border.

Comment: Are you facing this problem only on IE, what about other browsers

Comment: Why are you zooming out so far?

Comment: Not sure about other browsers, our project supports only IE browser.

Comment: I know this is not a very practical scenario, but our clients do tend to test with zoom in/out.

Comment: The border disappears even at a zoom out at 65%.

Comment: Why do they test that far though? If they can't tell you why then you are wasting your time.

Comment: There is no such thing as a HALF pixel, so zooming introduces obvious limitations.

Comment: Well if you simply draw a textbox(bydefault borders) and play with zoom out, you will never notice this issue.

Comment: I guess, there might be something wrong in code.

Comment: Is this a case of the anoying IE peekaboo bug ? http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html ? Try adding hasLayout to your containers with : min-width: 0;  and see if it's your case.